# Intersection of equipotential surfaces with different values and conservation of energy

Tags: energy-conservation, electric-fields

Can the intersection of two equipotential surfaces with different values be thought of as a contradiction of conservation of energy?

I started thinking that at the point of intersection of two such surfaces (which is impossible), there would be an infinitely large change in the potential over an infinitely small change in space, hence the work done on a charge would be infinite in magnitude if it were to pass through this point since the electric field strength is equal to the potential gradient, hence the principle of conservation of energy is disobeyed.

Is this reasoning correct and if so, is there a way of interpreting such a scenario in terms of conservation of energy rather than simply by the definitions of equipotential surfaces?

Comment: It is a contradiction...

Comment: Can't we say that potential at the point of intersection would be two , which is a bizzare thing in itself...?

Comment: Equipotentials are just level surfaces, and the concept of level surfaces can be applied to many quantities other than energy.  For example, consider a map of temperature in a solid.  The intersection of two level surfaces of temperature would be just as much of a logical contradiction as the intersection of two equipotentials, but it can't really be thought of in terms of a violation of conservation of energy.